# NodeJS: if I return mysql data to client in the end of request does it mean that having callbacks doesn't make sense?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.
I need to query Mysql and return that data to client synchronously.
If I do so does it mean that I block Reactor even if I use evented Mysql lib?
How should I do it correctly?

Comment: Why don't you send the data upon callback ?

Comment: If you're using an evented MySQL library, it's _impossible_ to return data synchronously unless you explicitly run a loop that blocks the reactor thread, since all I/O is by default asynchronous.

Comment: @billy: will it send in same response?

Comment: @BrandonTilley: so NodeJS is not for such job?

Comment: @sergey_mo What do you mean? Node.js is great at I/O bound tasks, but you _have to embrace Node.js' asynchronous style_. Trying to force a synchronous style will only result in pain. Check out http://nodecasts.net/episodes/5-thinking-asynchronously if you're interested in a bit more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that fake example will answer your question :

```
var http = require('http');
var db = require('db');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    db.query('fake query', function(data){
        res.send(data);
    }

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Even if you don't send your response syncronously, it's ok, that is how node work. I struggled with that concept at first, too.

Comment: Thanks, Billy. Does it mean that Node keeps connection alive (until the  callback will fire) despite the fact that Reactor is starting to process next request?

Comment: Of course, the connection stays opened. The example above has the same effect as this `http.createServer(function (req, res) { res.send(db.query('fake query')); })...` would have if node was syncronous.

Comment: node is single threaded : the callback will be executed when the database executes it, therefore sending the response to the client through the opened connexion.